# PHP simple HTML DOM parse

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to extract some information from some html code using dom parser, but I'm stuck at a point.

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="user">me:</div>
        <div class="post">I am an apple</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="user">you:</div>
        <div class="post">I am a banana</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="user">we:</div>
        <div class="post">We are fruits</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will print the users.

```
$users= $html->find('div[class=user]');
foreach($users as $user)
    echo $user->innertext;
```

This will print the posts.

```
$posts = $html->find('div[class=post]');
foreach($posts as $post)
    echo $post->innertext;
```

I want to print them together, and not sepparately, like so:

```
me:
I am an apple
you:
I am a banana
we:
We are fruits
```

How can I do this using the parser?

Comment: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) maybe?

Comment: if your html is as you have shown, you can use `strip_tags()` to get your output in very simple way

Comment: strip_tags will sepparate the code from text, what I want to do is parse, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the markup you provided, you can just point out the children of the main div (div#posts), then loop all children. Then for each children just get the first and second ones:

```
foreach($html->find('div#posts', 0)->children() as $post) {
    $user = $post->children(0)->innertext;
    $post = $post->children(1)->innertext;
    echo $user . '<br/>' . $post . '<hr/>';
}
```

Though I would really suggest use `DOMDocument` with this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@id="posts"]/div[@class="post"]');
foreach($elements as $posts) {
    $user = $xpath->evaluate('string(./div[@class="user"])', $posts);
    $post = $xpath->evaluate('string(./div[@class="post"])', $posts);
    echo $user . '<br/>' . $post . '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: Again, what if I don't know if there are more children? I want to parse the exact specific divs.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc the problem with it is that what if there are multiple divs, with classes like that? since the html markup you gave sets specific placement on those values you want, getting it thru children seems straight to the point. anyways you could also use the `->class` property to check it also, `->class == "user"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you can use `find()` with comma separator format. Try this:

```
$posts = $html->find('div.post');
foreach($posts as $post){
  $children = $post->find('div.user,div.post');
  foreach($children as $child){
    echo $child->class.' -- ';
    echo $child->innerText(); echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
user -- me:
post -- I am an apple
user -- you:
post -- I am a banana
user -- we:
post -- We are fruits
```

Comment: This works in this format, but what if I don't know if there are other childs?

Comment: This will not make a difference between users and posts, though.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc `$child->class` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
$users= $html->find('div[class=user]');
$posts = $html->find('div[class=post]');
foreach($users as $i=>$user){
    echo $user->innertext."<br>";
echo $posts[$i]->innertext;
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This will fail because there are more "div class=post" than there are div class=user. (very poor format design)